# Why are ligand orbitals always lower in energy than the metal orbitals in the ligand field theory?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, ligand-field-theory

The below image has been used to represent the ligand field theory for transition metals:

[image]

(Source: https://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch12/ligand.php)

Also, other similar images are available on other sites/books which portray the LFT.
My doubt is that by looking at these images, it seems that the ligand orbitals are always lower in energy than the Metal orbitals, is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an example of some specific compounds in which this is not the case? I think you'll have a hard time finding very many. Common ligand atoms are generally pretty small with low energy orbitals, eg O, N, F, Cl, C, S, P, so in a generic scheme, assuming ligand orbitals are low seems appropriate. One compound that seems likely to go against the trend is $\ce{TiCl4}$, but I'm not sure the exact numbers.